# Add highlighting to new Admin Dashboard Menu Item

Tags: admin-menu, add-menu-page

I have implemented a Custom menu item in my wordpress dashboard using the following command in the functions.php

```
function create_menu() {
    $settings_page = add_menu_page('Edit_Post_69', 'Edit_Post_69', 'add_users', '/post.php?post=69&action=edit', '', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/editicon.png', 2);
}
```

This works great and has added the icon into the dashmenu, included the icon and when clicked, takes me to the Edit Post page on post #69.

[image]

The problem I am facing is that even though I have clicked my custom link, the page it is currently on is the Edit Post page,  this causes the Highlighted arrow to be on the Post section rather than my custom section as in the image below.

[image: snapshot2]

What I need is for my custom item to be highlighted as well,  I have tried looking at filters and dug out _wp_menu_output, the idea being to filter the html and change the id class of the item to give it its highlighting.

Can anyone point me in the right direction of resolving this issue?

Comment: Welcome to WPSE & +1 for the nicely formed Question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability is high that no hook will exist for that...

But it can be solved with jQuery:

```
add_action( 'admin_head-post.php', 'wpse_58567_highlight_menu_item' );

function wpse_58567_highlight_menu_item()
{
    global $post;

    if( 69 != $post->ID )
        return;

    ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
                $('#toplevel_page_post-post-69-action-edit').removeClass('wp-not-current-submenu').addClass('current');
                $('#toplevel_page_post-post-69-action-edit').find('a:last').addClass('current');
            });     
        </script>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: That is perfect,  I have been trying to come up with a solution for so long now!  Thanks for taking the time to reply

Comment: I am now trying to move on with this function and convert it so that it uses the post name instead of the Id.  I have created a new question at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/59050/combine-two-functions-highlight-menu-item-by-post-name-instead-of-id  -  Any chance you could look in?

Comment: Thanks Brasofilo, Very active member of the WP community!  I see your name everywhere those days ;) 
Anyway, if I have to resort to javascript I will but... isn't there a "non-hacky" way to do this now (meaning 2 years later)?